# This was my father's and grandfather's patent. Can you tell me if this is expired or can it be renewed?

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [US2949381](https://www.google.com/patents/US2949381)

Answer (score 1):

The patent must have expired many years ago. Patents can't be "renewed". It is the basic principle with patents that in return for exclusive ownership for a fixed period of time, once expired anyone can use the technology.

Patents filed before June 8th 1995 expire 17 years after the issue date. After that it is 20 years from the filing date. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent_in_the_United_States)

Comment: How long are they for?  If they all vary, how do you find out?  Thanks.

Comment: It used to be 17 years from the issue date. Now it is 20 years from the application date.

Comment: @Jane Steinhardt: If you find my answer adequate, please accept it.

Comment: @Jane Steinhardt: I appreciate your thanks, but you still would love for you to accept my answer. Look for a check box near the answer.